# Android Annotation switch between different datatype

Tags: android, annotations

Can annotation in Android receive two different data type or do the conversion internally? So that it can read both data type. For example a usual annotation:

```
@StringDef({CheckInReward.NEW, CheckInReward.USED})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface CheckInReward{
  String NEW = "NEW";
  String USED = "USED"; }
```

So let say if backend pass me this status in integer format (new = 1, used = 2). But I don't want to create a new annotation file, can I reuse this file but tweak something inside? like

```
@StringDef({CheckInReward.NEW, CheckInReward.USED})
@IntDef({CheckInReward.new, CheckInReward.used})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface CheckInReward{
  String NEW = "NEW";
  String USED = "USED";
  int new = 1;
  int used = 2; }
```

I don't know is there any similar question but as my searching doesn't show any result. I know this is not the second piece of code is not working. Just an example defining my question.

Comment: There isn't a built annotation that I know of that can handle two different data types. Why would it need too? Why is your backend providing your app with different data? Is it out of your control? Having a consistent data type makes writing and maintaining code easier.

Comment: @WadeWilson because there are other places required string format annotation to proceed. But now the backend want to return data in another datatype and they don't plan to follow older datatype. So I am looking is there any way to do this.

Comment: The easiest way would be to have a converter object that you pass in the result from your backend and always convert it to your desired type in the app.

Comment: @WadeWilson If I really can't find any other solutions I will try that. Thank you so much.